# How to get WPF Image control to linearly interpret color channels from WriteableBitmap?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, wpf-controls

I have a C++ library which returns a pointer to a `float` array representing an image, with each pixel being made up of 4 floats, or one for each RGBA color channel. I also have a WPF `Image` control which needs to display this image.

To this end I am using `WriteableBitmap` as follows:

```c#
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlMoveMemory", SetLastError = false)]
public static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, uint count);

private static readonly int renderWidth = 1280;
private static readonly int renderHeight = 720;
private static readonly Int32Rect dirtyRect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, renderWidth, renderHeight);
private static readonly uint byteLength = (uint)(renderWidth * renderHeight * 16);

private WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap;
private IntPtr pixelPtr; // Assigned elsewhere

public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
    writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(renderWidth, renderHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Rgba128Float, null);
    renderImage.Source = writeableBitmap; // renderImage is a WPF Image control
}

public void NewStartImage() {
    writeableBitmap.Lock();
    CopyMemory(writeableBitmap.BackBuffer, pixelPtr, byteLength);
    writeableBitmap.AddDirtyRect(dirtyRect);
    writeableBitmap.Unlock();
}
```

`NewStartImage()` is called whenever the native library is done processing the data represented by `pixelPtr`. Now all this works fine, except that for some reason the colors are all brighter when displayed in the `Image` control than they are in the original data.

The change in brightness seems to be following some sort of square law. Here are some comparisons of the original Red channel value vs the displayed value:

| Original Red Channel | Displayed Red Channel |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0.1 | 0.34 |
| 0.5 | 0.73 |
| 0.8 | 0.9 |
| 1 | 1 |

I also ruled out any problems with the copying of memory by checking the values stored in the `BackBuffer`, and they matched up with the original values.

How can I make the WPF `Image` control display the original colors without reiterating the entire array or something similarly expensive?

Comment: How are you measuring the displayed color channel values?

Comment: @Clemens Screenshot and the MS Paint / Photoshop eyedropper. It's also pretty obvious with the naked eye.

Comment: Could that just be the difference between `sRGB` and `scRGB`, which is used by the 128Float PixelFormats? I did a quick test and converted Bgr32 color channel values linearly to a float buffer to construct a Rgba128Float bitmap. The brightness difference is pretty obvious.